# Android Landscape to portrait handling Data

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have develop a app for tablet  in which i have landscape and portrait both ,
i made different  ui designs for both screens ,
I tried using onconfig change = orientation  in manifest and onconfig change in java code 
the problem is how to handle the data in screen orientation.

please please please friends help me in this.. 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hm what kind of data do you want to handle? Can you make an example`?

Comment: I am getting some json data from server and displaying it in list view and textview and maps etc..